# Adding new objects to dynamic array

Tags: c++, object, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to write function to add objects name Hotel to dynamically allocated array. Problem is, while my code can add the first one, it fails to add anything further than that. Here is the code responsible for adding new objects.

```
void HotelReservationSystem::addHotel( const std::string name, const int numFloors, const int *numRooms)
{
    if ( hotelNum == 0 && hotels == NULL){
        hotels = new Hotel[1];
        Hotel hotelA ( name, numFloors, numRooms);
        hotels[0] = hotelA;
        hotelNum++;
        std::cout << "Hotel " << name << " is added." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < hotelNum; x++){
        if ( name == hotels[x].getName())
            std::cout << "\n" << "Hotel " << name << " already exists." << std::endl;
            return;
    }
    Hotel* temp = new Hotel[hotelNum+1];
    for ( int x = 0; x < hotelNum; x++){
        temp[x] = hotels[x];
    }
    temp[hotelNum] = Hotel ( name, numFloors, numRooms);
    delete [] hotels;
    hotels = temp;
    hotelNum++;
    std::cout << "Hotel " << name << " is added." << std::endl;
}
```

So far i cant detect anything wrong with this code.

Comment: *grumble grumble* Whats wrong is that your not just using vectors (now I'll actually read your code)

Comment: "So far i cant detect anything wrong" - you're juggling pointers rather than using `std::vector`. You're almost certainly going to make mistakes doing that, unless you're considerably smarter than me.

Comment: Hrm...My guess would be something in hotel. What is the exact error you are getting? Can we see Hotel?

Comment: Is your goal to build a Hotel Reservation System, or to get bogged down in memory management and trying to create home-made dynamic arrays?  If it's the former, then use `std::vector` -- this will shift your focus from trying to do this memory management yourself to actually developing and finishing your program (the  Hotel reservation System).

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int x = 0; x < hotelNum; x++){
    if ( name == hotels[x].getName())
        std::cout << "\n" << "Hotel " << name << " already exists." << std::endl;
        return;
}
```

Here, the `return` is not part of the `if` statement. Your code will just `return` in the first iteration. You need to put braces around those two lines.

Of course, as the comments say, you shouldn't be doing memory management like this yourself. Use `std::vector` instead. Your function would become only a few lines.

Comment: Well, problem is vectors are not an option for me at the moment. Other than this seems to be it. I am kinda embarassed that i have missed that so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any declaration for the variable "hotels".

Comment: We can assume it's a member of `HotelReservationSystem`.